# What happens if we run 415V 3 phase motor running on full load on to a 240V 3 phase supply?

Tags: motor, inverter, three-phase

I have a 415V 3 phase motor, but during emergency situation a 110V DC to 220VAC 3 Phase inverter comes into place. What will be the effects on the motor

Comment: What does the motor manufacturer say?

Comment: There is nothing mentioned by the manufacturer. The Inverter part came later into the design as a result this problem.

Comment: Have you tried asking them? Also, have you considered that the 220Vac invertor actually produces a line-to-line voltage that is 381 volts?

Comment: Is your inverter 220 VAC or 240 VAC? Your question is inconsistent. Note that 240 VAC phase-to-neutral in a Y configuration is the same thing as 415 VAC phase-to-phase.

Comment: Could it be possible one piece of equipment is stating line-line (usual for 3ph equipment) and the other stating phase voltage (typical for aerospace and equipment that can operate single phase).

Comment: Well sorry for the delay, No it is 220VAC Line to Line from the inverter, as per my understanding if we do this speed might decrease a little due to V/flux and flux saturates, but not a lot, hence power consumed would be nearly same but current nearly doubles, is this what might happen? .... BTW manufacturer of motor say he does'nt know what might happen. If current doubles and that's it then no problem,because motor is not running on full load it is running at around 75%

Answer (score 1):

> I have a 415V 3 phase motor, but during emergency situation a 110V DC
> to 220VAC 3 Phase inverter comes into place. What will be the effects
> on the motor

From this we can assume you are in the UK since 415Vac is the historic domestic line-line voltage for 240Vac phase.  As part of the EU harmonization that occurred in 2006, the voltage across the continent were also "harmonized" this meant the the UK single phase 230V was to be referred to as 220V and thus the line-line voltage is 400V, down from 415V. In practice the specification provides a +10% tolerance and thus the UK didn't actually lower the voltage.

Since it is conventional to refer to the line voltage in a three-phase system the question arises, this **110V DC to 220VAC 3 Phase inverter** does it refer to phase voltage or line voltage?

if the inverter refers to phase voltage, the output voltage will be 400Vac line-line and thus there will be no difference seen (within operating specification). If however it really is 220Vac line-line the reduction in line voltage will reduce the operating velocity and torque capability of the machine and depending on what the mechanical load is, could result in a stall or worse.

In short, read the inverter specifications closely and determine whether the output voltage is PHASE or LINE

Answer (score 0):

If the winding is a star (Y) connected winding and you have access to the star point in the terminal box, just connect it in delta as shown. Then it will be converted to 240V and work normally. The only difference will be that the current will be √3 x the 415V current.

[image]

Comment: you cannot reconfigure live if an emergency generator kicks in

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the emergency inverter kicking in. The 220V is probably phase voltage anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Torque is related to the voltage squared, so your starting torque and pull up torque will be decreased to about (220/415)^2 = 0.33 of the rated values. You may have trouble starting any loads in this situation.

The angular velocity = 2 x 3.14 x RPM / 60.
RPM = 120 x frequency of AC power / no of poles of motor.
Anyway RPM will not increase. So angular velocity will not increase.

Power = Torque x Angular velocity.
In this case power is proportional to torque.
So power @ 230 volt will be 0.33 x power @ 415 volt.

If the load on motor is equivalent to only 0.33 times of rated motor power;
Then current consumption @ 230 volt will be 0.33 x 415 / 230 = 0.6 times of current consumption @ 415 volt.

So star connection at 230 volt is ideal for low power consumption and increased life **if the load on your motor is equivalent to only 0.33 times of rated power of motor**.

Answer (score -1):

Ignoring changes to efficiency and power factor if the output power stays the same, then the input power must stay the same and the only way for that to happen when the voltage decreases is for the current to increase.  If this causes the current to go above the rated current, then your motor will start to overheat and you could see shortened life.  In your situation, \$\frac{415}{220}=1.88\$, so the current should increase by about \$1.88\$ times the normal current.

However, a torque is related to the voltage squared, so your starting torque and pull up torque will be decreased to about \$(\frac{220}{415})^2=0.33\$ of the rated values.  You may have trouble starting any loads in this situation.

Comment: Sorry, but I had to downvote. See Dave Tweed's comment. This is 3-phase power, and it can be specified in different ways.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, if Karthik Shetty comes back and clarifies what his voltage is, I will update my answer.  Or do you think I should make the answer more general, not including specific voltages?

Comment: Voltage is 220V Line to Line 3 Phase